# Overflow issues with dynamically sized canvas, sidepanels, and flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am making a web based game editor. The main interface is a CSS grid which houses different components (asset browser, file menu, etc.) as well as tabs to switch between the different editor windows, and the editor window itself.

The editor window contents switches out based one which tab is selected, but most consist of a collapsible left and right panel, and a canvas in the center that needs to dynamically resize itself to fit between the two side panels. Even though the current JavaScript and CSS seems like it should be working, there always seems to be overflow issues and weird leftover spacing between components.

The main app is designed in Vue, but I managed to replicate the problem in vanilla HTML5. The example code is below, and can be run completely locally if you wanted to try debugging it.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<style>
    html, body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #mainGrid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "cell1 cell2"
            "cell3 editorWindow";
        grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #editorWindow{
        grid-area: editorWindow;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #lPanel{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        background: #FFAAAA;
    }

    #lPanelContents{
        display: block;
        width: 150px;
    }

    #canvasWrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #rPanel{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #AAFFAA;
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
        resizeCanvas();
    }

    function resizeCanvas(){
        let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        let wrapper = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        /*
        by sizing canvas to 1, it lets the wrapper dynamically shrink again
        allowing the canvas to then set itself to the new shrunken dimensions.
        This works with the left side panel, but breaks again when the right panel is added.
        */
        canvas.width = 1;
        canvas.height = 1;

        canvas.width = wrapper.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = wrapper.clientHeight;

        ctx.fillStyle = "#AAAAFF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.fillText("Canvas", 10, 10);
    }

    function collapsePanel(){
        let panel = document.getElementById("lPanelContents");
        let expandBtn = document.getElementById("lPanelExpand");

        panel.style.display = "none";
        expandBtn.style.display = "block";
        resizeCanvas();
    }

    function expandPanel(){
        let panel = document.getElementById("lPanelContents");
        let expandBtn = document.getElementById("lPanelExpand");

        panel.style.display = "block";
        expandBtn.style.display = "none";
        resizeCanvas();
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="mainGrid">
        <div id="editorWindow">
            <div id="lPanel">
                <div id="lPanelContents">
                    Left Panel
                    <br />
                    <button onclick="collapsePanel()">CollapsePanel</button>
                </div>
                <div id="lPanelExpand" style="display: none;">
                    <button onclick="expandPanel()">&gt;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="canvasWrapper">
                <canvas id="canvas">
                    //Error loading HTML5 canvas
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="rPanel">
                Right Panel
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The spacing around the outside is filled with stuff in the actual app, but doesn't seem to contribute to the problem so I left it out of the example.

The desired result would be no page overflow, with the canvas shrinking to fit both sidepanels on screen at once, and no spacing between the canvas and the right panel.